# SKScene is not deallocating in xcode

Tags: memory-management, sprite-kit, skscene

I have an SKScene that is not being deallocated at any time during gameplay.... I have nilled out the scene, removed it from its parent view and the dealloc method is still never getting hit. The scene is also set to weak (although on iPhone 5s it deallocates the scene immediately if it is set to weak). Eventually, the game crashes after running out of memory from scenes running in the background.

Comment: So you have done [spriteView presentScene:nil];? Can you please post some code.

Comment: most likely you have a retain cycle. Run analyze build and instruments to find it. A common situation of a retain cycle would be if you add a custom node subclass to the scene, and that subclass has a strong reference to the scene. Node retains scene, scene retains node. Similarly if two child node of the scene have a strong reference to each other.

Comment: Thank you both. Turns out that I had some strong references that should have been weak....

Comment: i've got the same problem - where could these strong references be? in .h are non ..

Comment: Mine were mostly UIViews that I had as properties. A few of them were in the .m and a few in the .h. Honestly though, it all depends on what you have as @property values.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it in an answer and mark that answer as the accepted answer. That way, other people wrestling with the same issue can quickly see how to fix it.

Comment: @Roecrew  [spriteView presentScene:nil] fixes the deallocating issue, but now the gamescene is black even though after I present the scene I want to show. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had some properties that had strong references when they should have been weak. This was causing the scene to be retained as the properties inside of it were not deallocating....

Comment: I might add that if you are a heavy user of blocks, make sure you nil those blocks holding a strong reference to self - that is when referencing ivars inside blocks.

Comment: How do I create weak references and where do I add these since I'm having the same issue? Thanks